# Produce a clock out (5 MHz) with a counter and a clock in (50 MHz)

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, design, clock, counter

I'm trying to solve previous years' tests in logic design and there's this question that I can't really solve..

So, it gives me an 8-bit counter and a clock in (clk_in) of 50 MHz and it asks to produce a clock out (clk_out) of a 5 MHz. How do we do that?

It also says that it has a clear button, when the clear is equal to one it clears and when it is equal to zero it counts.

Any ideas? (It asks us to design the circuit.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider how to make an "is-it-10" recogniser out of gates; feed the counter outputs into the recogniser; feed the yes-it-is-10 signal into the clear input (for one clk_in clock).

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more clearly cause I didn't get it?

Comment: I would use a divide by five followed by a toggle FF to get a 50/50 duty cycle.

Comment: @jonathanjo and many others here are assuming that the counter has available 8 outputs from each of its counting stages. Use those outputs to sense with logic gates when the count has incremented to ten. Or five as Oldfart suggests.

Comment: To elaborate more on @glen_geek, it takes 10 clock cycles at 50MHz to get the 5MHz signal. So you could start the counter at 0 and when the counter reaches 9 (the 0 value is counted too), you can use an AND gate to detect the binary value 1001. At that point, clear the counter (with the same output from the AND) and restart the count.

Comment: Alright, so because the exam is tomorrow morning... When it gives me an clock of x frequency and the clock out needs to be of x/10 it means that it will take 10 seconds to reach this clock out.. so since we start from 0, we need the 9th second to 1) reset the circuit and what I don't understand is 2) what does it mean by clock out? It means a pulse kind of? Because big6 said that when it has counted 10 seconds I need to clear it (I get why) but explaining the meaning of clock out  would be very helpful!

Comment: not 10 sec, 10 clk in cycles to get 1 clk out cycle.  The duty cycle depends how it is done.  1/10 could be 10% duty cycle (Johnson Counter or Shift register counter or any logic arrangement , but for 50% you divide by 5 with 3 FF then divide by 2 with the 4th FF.